# how to fix django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library on GAE

Tags: django, postgresql, google-app-engine, postgis

I want to do the functionality of finding the places near me. It's about restaurants, so I have my location (latitude, longitude), and I need to get the closest restaurants within a given radius.

I'm using django 2.1.7 and postgres 11.2. For the geolocation and geospacial queries postgis extension.

On my computer it's working properly.

This is the snippet of my code:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D

point = Point(float(latitude), float(longitude))
query = Restaurant.objects.filter(location__dwithin=(point, D(km=km))).order_by('location')
```

The configuration for DB is:

```
# [START db_setup]
if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):
    # Running on production App Engine, so connect to Google Cloud SQL using
    # the unix socket at /cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/blog:us-central1:mb',
            'USER': 'user',
            'PASSWORD': 'password',
            'NAME': 'blog',
            'PORT': '5432'
        }
    }
else:
    # Running locally so connect to either a local MySQL instance or connect to
    # Cloud SQL via the proxy. To start the proxy via command line:
    #
    #     $ cloud_sql_proxy -instances=[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]=tcp:3306
    #
    # See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-connect-proxy
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'USER': 'user',
            'NAME': 'db_name',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
# [END db_setup]
```

The deployment is running on a GAE instance, and the postgres is on a Cloud SQL instance.

When I do the deploy the page throws a 502 Bad Gateway and the command `gcloud app logs tail -s default` says:

`2019-03-29 00:52:41 default[20190328t173044]  Traceback (most recent call last):    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker      worker.init_process()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 104, in init_process      super(ThreadWorker, self).init_process()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process      self.load_wsgi()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi      self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi      self.callable = self.load()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load      return self.load_wsgiapp()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp      return util.import_app(self.app_uri)    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app      __import__(module)    File "/srv/main.py", line 1, in <module>      from marcobetetaapi.wsgi import application    File "/srv/marcobetetaapi/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>      application = get_wsgi_application()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application      django.setup(set_prefix=False)    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup      apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate      app_config.import_models()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models      self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)    File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)    File "/srv/recommendations/models.py", line 1, in <module>      from django.contrib.gis.db import models    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>      import django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions  # NOQA    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/functions.py", line 4, in <module>      from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import BaseSpatialField, GeometryField    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 3, in <module>      from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>      from .fields import (  # NOQA    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/fields.py", line 2, in <module>      from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSException, GEOSGeometry    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>      from .collections import (  # NOQA    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/collections.py", line 9, in <module>      from django.contrib.gis.geos.geometry import GEOSGeometry, LinearGeometryMixin    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/geometry.py", line 8, in <module>      from django.contrib.gis import gdal    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>      from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/datasource.py", line 39, in <module>      from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/driver.py", line 5, in <module>      from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/prototypes/ds.py", line 9, in <module>      from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py", line 43, in <module>      % '", "'.join(lib_names)  django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal", "GDAL", "gdal2.2.0", "gdal2.1.0", "gdal2.0.0", "gdal1.11.0", "gdal1.10.0", "gdal1.9.0"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.`

I've reading previews questions about the same problem, and they say that GDAL library is not supported by GAE, but those questions are from years ago. I'd like to know if know it's supported or what could I change to make it works again using django and postgres.

Comment: How do you have configured the connection to this Cloud SQL instance that you've mentioned?

Comment: Yes, I already updated my question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348004/gdal-in-flexible-environment