# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] in deploying flex environment in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gdal

I'm trying to get GDAL to work in Google App Engine. I've been following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348004/gdal-in-flexible-environment) post. I've got a similar app.yaml and Dockerfile alongside my script and requirements.txt as a part of my deployment [folder](https://github.com/isodrosotherm/gcloud_gdal). I'm getting the following error after running

```
gcloud app deploy
```

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Flex operation projects
/flex-env-gdal-api/regions/us-central1/operations/230ef197-33ab-43ee-bbac-85b53e6c8fd0 

error [INTERNAL]: An internal error occurred while processing task 
/appengine-flex-v1/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>
2020-07-20T19:50:34.913Z71509.jo.14: Deployment Manager operation 
flex-env-gdal-api/operation-1595274635522-5aae4d1f830ec-81a3f5de-b5b771bf 

errors: [code: "RESOURCE_ERROR" location: "/deployments/aef-default 20200720t144747/resources/aef-default-20200720t144747" 
message: "{\"ResourceType\":\"compute.beta.regionAutoscaler\",\"ResourceErrorCode\":\"403\",\"ResourceErrorMessage\":{\"code\":403,\"message\":\"The caller does not have permission\",\"status\":\"PERMISSION_DENIED\",\"statusMessage\":\"Forbidden\",
\"requestPath\":\"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/flex-env-gdal-api/regions/us-central1/autoscalers\",
\"httpMethod\":\"POST\"}}"
]
```

After doing some looking around, Error Response [13] seems to be associated with permissions. I have the Owner role in the IAM, so I'm not sure that's the issue. If anybody has any suggestions of things to try, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've ran into similar issues and the workaround was to specify the number of instances to a maximum of two, this can be done either through [manual_scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#manual-scaling) or max_num_instances while using [automatic scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#automatic_scaling).

Your app.yaml file would something similar to:

*Using automatic scaling*

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT mysite.wsgi
runtime_config:
  python_version: 3.7
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 2
```

*Using manual scaling:*

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT mysite.wsgi
runtime_config:
  python_version: 3.7
manual_scaling:
  instances: 2
```